# Add multiple event handlers for one event in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, xaml

in procedural code in can do the following:

```
// Add two event handler for the button click event
button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button1_Click_1);
button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button1_Click_2);
```

But how can I add *multiple* event handlers for the button's click event in XAML?
Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Why do you want this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to do this too. I want to be able to subscribe to events in the XAML properly, not in a restricted way (mostly because it gives tidier code & it(XAML) feels incomplete without this)
Either semi-colon separation or just having multiple <event>="<handler>" options would be nice

Comment: This would allow composing the event handlers for specific elements freely from general procedures, instead of having to write a procedure specifically for each element only for this composition. In short: it would be shorter and sweeter.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot subscribe more than one event handler in XAML. You can however achieve the same effect by subscribing a single event handler and then calling two or more methods from the event handler.

```
    private void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonOnClick1();
        ButtonOnClick2();
    }

    private void ButtonOnClick1()
    {
        //Do something...
    }

    private void ButtonOnClick2()
    {
        //Do something...
    }
```

Comment: I think this misses the point. Functional composition would always be possible. But writing that composition in the XAML would avoid a specific handler for a button.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify multiple handlers in `xaml` like this :

```
   <Style  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">            
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="ChangeBackground1"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="ChangeBackground2"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="ChangeBackground3"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="ChangeBackground4"/>
   </Style>
```