# Is it possible that the EventSetter of a Style runs side by side with another event handler?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, click, eventsetter

I have defined a `Style` for a `Button` in WPF. In that style, I want the button's background to be changed when it is clicked. For example:

```
<Style x:Key="TheButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="ChangeBackground"/>
</Style>
```

and in the code behind:

```
private void ChangeBackground(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    if(btn != null)
        btn.Background = Brushes.SeaShell;
}
```

So this a general style that is applied to several `Button`s, each performing a different job. Is it possible that the above event-handler could run along with the other event handler that is specified for each button when they are clicked?

If I specify a `Click` handler for a button that uses this style, does it override the `EventSetter` or the `EventSetter` has the higher priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Local value always takes precedence.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx)

So, normal Click handler will fire followed by your EventSetter one.

Comment: Do you mean they will both run? No overriding?

Comment: Both will run, as there can be multiple handlers for same event.

Comment: Now I think that it's better to accept your answer. But as the last question, [here it says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3383719/5358284) there can't be multiple event handlers for a single event. What am I missing?

Comment: He might not be aware of this trick. Using += syntax one can attach any number of event handlers, but how you will do that in xaml ?

Comment: @polfosol See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383695/add-multiple-event-handlers-for-one-event-in-xaml/39813889#39813889

Answer (score 1):

I would use some XAML magic to change the Background (but that's a matter of taste). The `Click` handler of the button works in parallel.

```
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation To="#FFFF0000" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```